# How to print a string that depends on the length of a matrix?

Tags: r

I am trying to print data files that will feed another software (AMPL solver).

Therefore, I need to print the data in a way that will be understood by the solver.

Here, I want to print as many `I1, I2, I3, I4, ...` that there are rows in a given matrix that I loop. I want to store this string in the variable setI that I will call in a `write.table` command.

I have tried the `paste` and the `cat` functions, but none of them produces what I want.

```
x1.list <- matrix(rbind(c(1,2),c(3,4)), ncol = 2)

for (j in 1:nrow(x1.list)) {
    setI <- cat(paste("I",j))
  }
```

With this command, I receive `I 1I 2` and it is not stored into `setI`. It should be `I1, I2`, without quotes.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: What if you try just `cat(paste0('I', 1:nrow(x1.list), collapse = ', '))`?

Comment: `cat` doesn't return anything. I'd recommend `setI <- paste()` on one line and `cat(setI)` on the next line. Though there won't be much point in overwrting `setI`  each time through the loop.

Comment: @utubun your solution works very well. I added `sep = ","` and I got `I1, I2, I3, I4, `. Do you know if it is possible to remove the last comma?

Comment: I didn't get it at first. See the updated comment: just change from `sep = ', '` to `collapse = ', '`

Comment: @utubun nice, thank you! So I can create `setI` without the `cat()` and use the `cat`when I call `setI` into my `write.table()`?

Comment: @Simon Certainly you can assign the output from `paste` (which is *character* vector) to variable `setI`, or any other variable, to `cat` it afterwards.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
x1.list <- matrix(rbind(c(1,2),c(3,4)), ncol = 2)

setI <- NULL
for (j in 1:nrow(x1.list)) {
  setI <- paste(setI,"I",j,",",sep="")
}

library('stringi')
setI <- stri_sub(setI, 1, -2)
```

This would return an output `setI` as `"I1,I2"` in your case.

Comment: @yizi zhou this is also a nice solution, but again can it be stored without the quotes?
Indeed, I will then call it there: `write.table(paste(setI, ";", x[1], x[2]))` and I need it without the quotes. The result would be 'I1, I2 ;118, 119`. Thank you!

Comment: Just use command `noquote(setI)` then you can get it without the quotes.